# Cartesian Product (Really Simple)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble visualizing this Cartesian Product while I'm studying for fun from this math book I've found. This is the image that I have in my book:

[image: Cartesian Product]

So, now I'm puzzled as to how an $S\times S$ product look like? Would it be a square since $S$ and $S$ are the same or would they both be on the same line cause direction matters. Really appreciate the help and I'm sorry in advance because of the stupidity in my question.

Comment: Visualisation of $S\times S$ looks like a square.

Comment: T can always be substituted for S, so `SxS` is a square.

Comment: Yes. But be careful. $(s_1,s_2)\neq (s_2;s_1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $S \times S$ would form a square. Why do they call $x^2$ squaring a number?

In fact, calling a number multiplied by itself a square goes way back to pythagoras who always gave geometrical interpretations of all things mathematical.